# Exception Handling for failed records using Map Reduce code ...Help Required

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

How to do exception handling for failed records and to re process the failed records in future using map reduce code(Required)....appreciated your help on this, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an exception handling inside your map function then you can add a specified key for those values (ex "ERROR PARSING" if you have string as key) and at your reducer write them at a log for future investigation.

Answer (score 0):

If something in data is not as per expectations and causing failures in processing, then simply mark that record for the re-processing by writing that into the logs, see example

```
 try{
        //Business logic goes here
        //write output of mapper if everything is as expected
    }catch(Ex e){
        //If something is not right control comes here, then dont break the execution flow
        //simply write the current record for re-validation for ex. re-processing.log something like this
    }
```

And then you can revisit this file later on time.

Comment: yeah I follow this approach at times. It is useful